# Знание или мышление?

Tags: c++

Сразу вопрос (пояснение ниже): Как решаются олимпиадные задачи? На каждую задачу уже есть определенный алгоритм и его можно адаптировать к задаче или новые (порой гениальные алгоритмы) придумываются с нуля?

На вопрос натолкнула [вот эта](http://codeforces.ru/contest/278/problem/A) весьма простая задача. Я бросился решать её в лоб, создав список элементов с ссылками на левый и правый элемент, затем просто просматривал элементы, подсчитывал расстояния и находил минимальное. Около 120 строчек кода.

А теперь решение пользователя [Delostik](http://codeforces.ru/profile/Delostik):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n,d[110],dist1,s,t;

int main(){
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cin>>d[i];
        d[i]+=d[i-1];
    }
    cin>>s>>t;
    if(s>t) swap(s,t);
    dist1=d[t-1]-d[s-1];
    cout<<min(dist1,d[n]-dist1);
}
```

Предложенное решение вызвало у меня ступор. Оно очень лёгкое, но как догадаться до него - я не знаю. Алгоритм просто смотрит, что меньше: расстояние от начальной до конечной станции или суммарное расстояние по кольцу минус расстояние от начальной до конечной станции.

Всё логично. Но как такие решения приходят в голову? Чем руководствуются олимпиадники? Давно проверенными алгоритмами для решения подобных задач или исключительно своей логикой?

Comment: Только совокупность знаний и логических способностей дают, как вы сказали, "*порой гениальные алгоритмы*". Если и есть иключения, то они только подтверждают правило.

Comment: @artyomdevyatov, одно с другим очень тесно связано. Не получится размышлять о том, чего не знаете.

Comment: Совершенно очевидно что в таких серьезных делах как придумывание нового эффективного алгоритма решения какой-нибудь полезной задачи в ход идет вообще все что может хоть как-то помочь делу. Собственные мозги, опыт и знания, пачки математических текстов, опросы людей сталкивавшихся с задачей, допросы ботаников аутистов с соседней парты и.т.д и.т.п.

Comment: Больше решенных задач по математике + много коддинга.

Comment: На этом примере хорошо видно, почему математиков учат 5 лет в институте, а программистов - 3 месяца на курсах

Comment: Простейший случай линейной динамики. Нарешивайте больше задач и будет вам успех.

Comment: Я вот совершенно не программист (математик), но мне пришло в голову именно такое решение (как в приведенном коде). Даже не представляю себе как решать эту задачу _по-другому_

Comment: @neofit, решать по другому - очень просто "в лоб". 2 раза идем по кругу. Считаем 2 суммы от s до t, и от t до s.

Просто индексируем массив с нуля

    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cin >> d[i];
    cin >> s >> t;
    
    s--, t--;
    for (sum1 = 0, i = s; i != t; i = (i+1)%n)
       sum1 += d[i];
    for (sum2 = 0, i = t; i != s; i = (i+1)%n)
       sum1 += d[i];
    cout << min(sum1,sum2);

Решение не столь элегантное, но о 120 строках кода речь не идет.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для решения олимпиадных задач -- да и во всяком творческом процессе -- нужно и то, и другое: и **интуиция** (то есть мышление, способность выдумать новое решение без чётких зацепок в условии), и **эрудиция** (то есть знание типичных и не вполне типичных задач).

При этом эти оба качества не только дополняют, но и помогают друг другу: эрудиция даёт множество других, известных задач, отталкиваясь от которых можно придумать решение данной вам задачи (или свести к ним одну из подзадач); интуиция же помогает увидеть и вычленить общее среди вашей задачи и того, что вам уже известно.

Таким образом, эрудиция (знания) -- это строительные блоки вашего решения, интуиция (мышление) же -- комбинирование этих блоков для решения поставленной задачи.

Перефразируя классика, "мышление без знаний слепо, знания без мышления мертвы".

Comment: Ну зачем же так редуцировать научное творчество к интуиции. Я конечно в курсе, что попытки полной формализации науки оказались несостоятельными (оговорюсь - это программа Гильберта в математике, как в других науках - не знаю). Но все таки интуиция - это отказ от логического анализа. Кто скажет что знания нельзя получать путем рассуждений пусть первым бросит в меня логарифмической линейкой

Comment: @renegator: ну, формально говоря, путей рассуждения бесконечно много. Из них надо же какой-то выбрать? (Задачи, в которых к-во путей рассуждения _можно_ сделать конечным, не считаются особенно интересными.) Этот выбор и есть интуиция.

С другой стороны, наверняка саму интуицию на основе накопленного опыта можно формализовать, мозг ведь не особо сложная штука.

Comment: Не очень представляю себе логику, в которой бесконечное количество возможностей рассуждения. Мой доцент помнится так рисовал женскую логику - в виде предиката: <любая посылка> -> <любой вывод>

Comment: @renegator: ЕМНИМС, любая, которая не сводима к формальной арифметике (то есть такая, к которой применима теорема Гёделя о неполноте).

Comment: Хотелось бы на этом дискуссию завершить, бо площадка для этого не подходит

Answer (score 6):

Чем больше решаешь задач и разбираешь чужие решения и придумываешь свои, тем больше задач будут для тебя типовыми, задачи очень похожи, но у каждой задачи своя особенность. Если ты знаешь какой то алгоритм (понимаешь, можешь его вывести если забыл или доказать), то очень большой класс задач ты сможешь решить придумав решение.

Answer (score 2):

1) когда читаю задачу, сразу вспоминаются подобные, и сразу всплываются решения.

2) читаю ограничения, и сразу пытаюсь понять особенность задачи, в чем сложность:

- проблема памяти
- проблема скорости
- просто придумать как решить (в лоб)

3) Если есть готовые решения в голове, просто его пишу. Если таковых нету, то приходится либо адаптировать, либо свой придумывать.

4) Придумывание своего алгоритма - очень творческое занятие. Можно попробовать поискать закономерности и т.д.

Например, читая задачу "Определите площадь выпуклого многоугольника" у меня вспоминается сразу один алгоритм.

Т.е. данное решение пришло в голову программиста из-за опыта в решении подобных задач.

Answer (score 1):

Часто решения подобного рода задач сводятся использованию "естественных" трюков, не противоречащих здравому смыслу. Для этой задачи например, достаточно вспомнить наши поезда или метро, там ведь пишут не расстояние между парами соседних вершин, а расстояние от начала до конкретной вершины.

Что касается решения очень сложных задач, или задач нового класса, то, как говорилось выше, нужны тренировки + разминка мозга. Вот, кстати, [хороший сайт](http://ru.brainexer.com/) на эту тему.

Гениальность и способности - вопрос сложный и спорный. [Прекрасное исследование на эту тему](http://www.forbes.ru/forbes/issue/2009-04/7255-pravilo-10000-chasov). Советую к прочтению.